# Really strange memory issue using ARC, object/value from first object in NSArray is suddenly nil?

Tags: ios, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

So I have this NSArray with NSDictionaries inside.

As you can see in the code there are actually two very equal for loops (don't mind why).

If you see the log, the key scheduleID in the first object in the second loop is suddenly nil...

I have no clue whatsoever how this is even possible. The object (NSDictionary) itself is not nil. I am using ARC.

```
UILocalNotification *mergedNotification = [notificationsWithEqualFireDates objectAtIndex:0];

    if ([notificationsWithEqualFireDates count] > 1) {
        NSMutableArray *mergedUserInfo = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (UILocalNotification *ln in notificationsWithEqualFireDates) {
            NSLog(@"Hmmm... %@", [ln.userInfo objectForKey:@"scheduleID"]);
            [mergedUserInfo addObject:ln.userInfo];
        }
        NSDictionary *mergedUserInfoDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:mergedUserInfo,@"array", nil];
        mergedNotification.userInfo = mergedUserInfoDictionary;
    }

    for (UILocalNotification *tempNotification in notificationsWithEqualFireDates) {
        NSManagedObject *managedObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"RegisteredNotifications" inManagedObjectContext:newMoc];
        [managedObject setValue:tempNotification.fireDate forKey:@"fireDate"];
        [managedObject setValue:[tempNotification.userInfo objectForKey:@"dateTimeOriginal"] forKey:@"dateTimeOriginal"];
        [managedObject setValue:[tempNotification.userInfo objectForKey:@"scheduleID"] forKey:@"scheduleID"];
        NSLog(@"Saving schedule: %@", [tempNotification.userInfo objectForKey:@"scheduleID"]);
    }
```

[image]

**UPDATE**
I was able to fix this issue by using the copy method:

```
UILocalNotification *mergedNotification = [[notificationsWithEqualFireDates objectAtIndex:0] copy];
```

Can somebody please explain why this was happening and why I need this copy method.
I would think that assigning an object from an NSArray to a variable would be to create a memory location, init it and then copy the value from the place in the array to the variable...

Comment: Why do all the objects have the same Core Data object ID?

Answer (score 0):

Guess:

Print `tempNotification.userInfo`.

It is probably the same as whatever you shoved into `mergedUserInfoDictionary`;   i.e. you are overwriting the `userInfo` entirely in that code.

Can't say conclusively because you don't show where `mergedNotification` comes from.

---

> Could you please explain how this is happening?

You are replacing the `userInfo` of the `NSNotification` instance in slot 0 of your array with a dictionary that no longer has the key you are looking up.

Comment: Right above the if I do this: `UILocalNotification *mergedNotification = [notificationsWithEqualFireDates objectAtIndex:0];`

Comment: Could you please explain how this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is that notificationsWithEqualFireDates is going out of scope somehow, it is an NSDictionary, correct?  Is it a property?  I encountered a case where a NSString went to nil that was set as a weak property in another class inside of a method, maybe something similar?  Suggest you look into that and/or post more code about the origin of notificationsWithEqualFireDates.  Another to try would be to set breakpoints and watch the stack as you go through each line above to see when it goes to nil...

Answer (score 0):

notificationsWithEqualFireDates is being released. Try using a property w/ strong reference.